# xaml menu bottom and top alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a left-aligned vertical menu which stretches to my entire screen.
I want the first three options to end in the top left and the last two options to be in the bottom left.
Whatever I try I can't get the last two options to align to the bottom.

My current XAML is this:

```
    <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="Option A" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Option B" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Option C"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Logout"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Settings" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Menu>
```

Current situation

[image: Current situation]

Desired situation

[image]

Edit:
I'd prefer to not use rows if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do not want to use rows, consider using a DockPanel. Also note that the bottom-docked items are in reverse order.

```
     <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="Option A" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Option B" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Option C" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Settings" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Logout" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    </Menu>
```

Comment: This verry elegant and flexible. I love this solution!
Its a bit of a shame that the bottom docked panels are reversed though, but it makes sence from an implementation point of view.